# Excel 2007 Indirect function in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Why do neither of the below work in conditional format formula's?

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()),0,1)<>""
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE),0,1)<>""
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to use INDIRECT here - can you explain what you are trying to do without reference to specific formulas?

Comment: @barry-houdini - I know that I can use (for example) =$d1 in the top most row, then copy down, however I am interested in knowing what part of the above doesn't work, and why. In actuality I am using =OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE),0,4-COLUMN())<>"", but I think that the issue is with the row() and/or column function inside indirect.

Comment: That formula works for me - if I apply it to A1:C1 then those cells are all formatted when I put a value in D1 - is that what you expect? What do you get, no formatting at all? What's the "Applies to" range?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be causing me problems here but I know that ROW and COLUMN can sometimes be problematic because they return "arrays" rather than numbers - one way round that is to use SUM function, e.g. `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&SUM(ROW())&"C"&SUM(COLUMN()),FALSE),0,SUM(4-COLUMN()))<>""`

Comment: @barry houdini - Ah. Interesting. I will try this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: We just had an 1.5 hour power outage.  Right as it started I realized I'd misspoken.

The 2nd one kind of works for me, but it only works with numbers. If I change it to the below it works for all cases:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE),0,1)<>""
```

You've got just a greater than sign - ">", which won't work as expected with numbers.

The first one doesn't work, and that's because you are specifying the whole row.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oops, another c&p error. Interesting, it doesn't work for me. Wish there was debug info given by the conditional formatting parser.

Comment: Major typos.  I hope it makes sense now!

Comment: The fault may not be yours. It is supposed to have a greater-than and less-than sign. Yet another issue with my c&p :(